# Fisheye for Winforms

Tags: winforms, controls

Does anybody if there is a **fisheye** (menu/pane) **windows forms** control like it is often seen in Ajax applications:
example: http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/fisheye.html

A googled around, but I only found this one at codeprojece:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/FishEyeMenu.aspx

Comment: There's also http://www.kinlan.co.uk/source_samples/FishEye.cs but it's only part of what would be needed

Comment: Are you opposed to using WPF?  I saw an awesome and quick example of the fisheye behavior just the other day using WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out : [DotNetBar BubbleBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/bubblebar.aspx). It works and looks pretty similar to FishEye.

Also FYI, if you download and register VB Express Edition 2008 (not sure on any other express edition) you get access to download a copy of the bubblebar as a thank you for registering (there is other stuff too). I do not recall the license on it, but I think it was a single install license.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Flash components . I have seen plenty of them on the internet. This is one fo them: http://www.shinedraw.com/animation-effect/flash-and-silverlight-fish-eye-menu/

Even Adobe Flare could help. You might need Adobe Flex builder to create one.